# Calling Remote Web Service -- "The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized"

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I am calling a remote service and authenticating using a certificate.  When testing with a Console App, everything works fine.  When calling from an ASP.NET Website (.NET 4.0, IIS7) I receive a response code of 401 -- Unauthorized.

I am adding the certificate using code such as:

```
var client = new TheGeneratedProxy();
client.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate("D:\cert.pfx", "myPassword"));
```

(NOTE: I have also loaded the .pfx into the local Certificate Store using IE.  The certificate is loaded into my "Personal" store -- so I suspect this to be the problem, since the Website will be running under a different account.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your IIS user (Network Service / ASPNET) doesn't have access to the certificate. In order to grant Network Service to access the certificate in the store, download the following tool: winhttpcertcfg (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=c42e27ac-3409-40e9-8667-c748e422833f&displaylang=en)

Now open command prompt and type:

```
winhttpcertcfg –g –c LOCAL_MACHINE\My –s ORGNAME –a "Network Service"
```

Please note that "Network Service" can be substituted with any other account. I.e. if you you have configured a custom user for your app pool, you should put this user as the value for the -a parameter.

ORGNAME should be substituted with the Organisation name you specified during the creation of your cert.